# How can I access the values in a named range using a dynamically generated reference (month name) and an adjacent column's values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I have an Excel workbook that contains 12 named ranges for each month of the year (`JanuaryTallies`, `FebruaryTallies`), each containing two columns, `Amount` and `Category`.

What I am trying to do is get the sum of all the "Amounts" which pertain to each "Category" for the *current month*. For example, given that it's currently May, I would like to be able to get the `SUM()` of all the values in the `Amount` column in the `MayTallies` named range, that have the value "Groceries" in the adjacent `Category` cell.

I know that I can get the name of the current month by using `=TEXT(TODAY(), "mmmm")` and generate the relevant range name using `=(TEXT(TODAY(), "mmmm") & "Tallies")`.

I also know that if these were individual tables rather than named ranges I could do use something like `SUMIFS(MayTallies[Amount], MayTallies[Category], "Groceries")`, but not only does this not seem to work with named ranges, I'm having trouble actually generating the named range within the formula dynamically.

Logically, I'm looking to be able to do something like:

`SUMIFS( 
     (TEXT(TODAY(), "mmmm") & "Tallies")[Amount], 
     (TEXT(TODAY(), "mmmm") & "Tallies")[Category], 
      "Groceries" )`

Could anyone point me in the direction on how to achieve this? Even some thoughts on both generating a named range reference with dynamic concatenation and some alternative to SUMIFS that uses named ranges would be helpful. Thanks.

EDIT: Update!
I have solved part of the problem by making these named ranges tables instead. This allows me to use `SUMIFS()`. Now I just need to figure out how to dynamically generate the reference.

Comment: You can use INDIRECT.

Comment: For which part? The concatenation? As an aside, I have solved part of the problem by making these named ranges tables instead.

Comment: No, to refer to a named range... you could use `INDEX` within to refer to the 2nd column.

Comment: I was able to combine INDIRECT with the conversion of the named ranges to tables. If you'd like to put it as the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Feel free to self-answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem in a partially roundabout way. I converted the named ranges into tables in order to allow for me to use `SUMIFS()` then used `INDIRECT()` as @BigBen recommended in the comments. The final formula was as follows:

`=SUMIFS((INDIRECT((TEXT(TODAY(),"mmmm")&"Tallies")&"[Amount]")), 
         (INDIRECT((TEXT(TODAY(),"mmmm")&"Tallies")&"[Category]")), 
          "Groceries")`